# Can't seem to load a managed dll from Installer during setup?

Tags: installshield, custom-action, installshield-2012

I'm developing an installer for an application which includes a Windows Service.  The service will need a username/password from the user in order to get information from our server, so I'd like to set that during install.  We also need to store that info in the Services config file so it has to be encrypted.

So I'd like the installer to call the same .dll the service uses when it encrypts the credentials.  I set up custom actions created through the custom action wizard.  I set it to "Call a public method in a managed assembly" and picked "Installed with the product" as the Location.  I'm able to pick the dll and the target function and set everything up through the wizard.  The path it resolves to in the installer log looks correct...

But I'm getting the error:

> Unable to load managed custom action assembly

So not sure what to do in order to get this working?

The second part of the question is, what happens if the end user doesn't have .NET 4 installed?  I'm going to set the installer to install it... but will there be problems or will we need to force a reboot partway through the install process?  If so I might just temporarily store things unencrypted and have the service encrypt them when it first runs... which at this point is probably the easy way, but it doesn't feel like the "correct" way. ;)

Comment: The service is running as the credentials that were inputted so why do you need the username and password in the config file.  Can you not use SSO/SSPI to connect to whatever it is you are connecting to?  If someone ever updates the credentials they won't know how to update the config file.

Comment: These are credentials to connect to a custom web service across the internet, not the credentials the service is running under.

Comment: Well, my general reccomendation whenever it comes to managed custom actions is to use Windows Installer XML's (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).  Google it. It's a very robust way of writing CA's that appear to MSI as Type 1 unmanaged (DLL) custom actions.  Very suitable for use with IntsallShield.

Comment: My other suggestion would be to explore use of the CredentialCache instead of coming up with your own way of encrpyting passwords in a config file.